# Multiline rows in a row at listboxes

Tags: c#, wpf

I want to display some data on a listbox but I don't want it to be seen as

" Sender:"Sender name" Title: " Title of subject" Subject:""  "

but as

"Sender:
 Title:
 Subject: 
"
so each row in a listbox should contain the above..each row shold look like above

is something like this possible? I would really appreciate if anyone can guide me to something or somewhere where I can start doing this.

I'm sorry for my bad English, thanks

Comment: You can create a DataTemplate for ListboxItem.

Answer (score 2):

You can write a DataTemplate refer the below code.

```
 <ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding}">
        <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                        <TextBlock Text="Sender :" />
                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Sender }" />
                    </StackPanel>
                    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                        <TextBlock Text="Title :" />
                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Title }" />
                    </StackPanel>
                    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                        <TextBlock Text="Subject :" />
                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Subject }" />
                    </StackPanel>
                </StackPanel>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
    </ListBox>
```